# HAProxy - Does it cache the configuration file

Tags: configuration, edit, haproxy

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to post this.  Please let me know if it is not.

Basically, exactly what the title of the question is.  I have an haproxy configration file where I'm trying to set the timeout to 3600s.  However, it seems that at random, the file will revert to a previous iteration, with much shorter timeout values.

What I set is as follows:

```
defaults
  log     global
  mode    http
  retries 3
  timeout client 3600s
  timeout connect 3600s
  timeout server 3600s
  option tcplog
  balance  roundrobin

listen admin
  bind 127.0.0.1:22002
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats show-node
  stats uri  /admin

listen  stats    :1936
  mode            http
  log             global

  maxconn 10

  timeout client 3600s
  timeout connect 3600s
  timeout server 3600s
  timeout queue   3600s

  stats enable
  stats hide-version
  stats show-node
  stats uri  /haproxy?stats
```

However, it somehow changes to the following:

```
defaults
  log     global
  mode    http
  retries 3
  timeout client 50s
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout server 50s
  option tcplog
  balance  roundrobin

listen admin
  bind 127.0.0.1:22002
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats show-node
  stats uri  /admin

listen  stats    :1936
  mode            http
  log             global

  maxconn 10

  clitimeout      100s
  srvtimeout      100s
  contimeout      100s
  timeout queue   100s

  stats enable
  stats hide-version
  stats show-node
  stats uri  /haproxy?stats
```

I have not found anything to indicate that haproxy 1.5 caches the configuration file, but I need to investigate all possibilities.  Simply put: is there anything in haproxy that can cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, HAProxy doesn't implement anything that could explain that behavior.

How was installed HAProxy ? What's your OS ?

If you have auditd on your server, you can add a rule to watch which process is modifying the configuration file :

```
auditctl -w /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf -p wa
```

Then watch for any activity in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

To delete the auditing :

```
    auditctl -W /etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf
```